# Destructor called one more time than I expected

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, output, destructor

Here is my min ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    B() { v.push_back(A()); v.push_back(A()); }
private:
    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

So, I got this output:

```
Constructor   // first push back
Destructor    // copy destroyed
Constructor   // second push back
Destructor    // copy destroyed
Destructor    // ???????????????
// B object goes out of scope and its vector too...
Destructor    // v[0] destructor called 
Destructor    // v[1] destructor called
```

Can someone shed some light please?

---

After following Dave's comment:

```
Constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: Try adding a log to the implicit copy constructor. Looks like your vector is reallocating memory when the second element is added, so needs to move its first element.

Comment: @Dave thanks, I updated my post.

Comment: @Dave the answers go down there vvvvvvvvvvvvv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding in an overloaded copy constructor and some indicator of which object is being acted upon sheds some light on the situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A(unsigned i): i(i) { std::cout << "Constructor " << i << std::endl; }
    A(const A& a) : i(a.i) { std::cout << "Copy constructor " << i << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor " << i << std::endl; }
    unsigned i;
};

class B {
public:
    B() { v.push_back(A(0)); v.push_back(A(1)); }
private:
    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

On the first push, we make a copy and destroy the temporary.  On the second push, we make a copy, then copy the first object, before destroying the first object and the temporary.  Finally, we destroy both objects.

I'd guess that the std::vector was first allocated with a capacity of 1, so the second push forced a re-allocation?  If I force a larger initial capacity (by calling `v.reserve(5)` before the first push), then the extra copy disappears.

Comment: No capacity used from me. A straight push_back. Thank you, perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are not tracking construction of `A`s using the default copy constructor. If you add a copy constructor and a message in it, the number of calls to constructors should match the number of calls to the destructor.

Comment: @gsamaras, do you still have some questions?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying declaration of class A as follows,

```
class A 
{
public:
  A() { std::cout << "Constructor " << this << std::endl; }
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor " << this << std::endl; }
};
```

running the program at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/
gives output:

Constructor 0x7fffecb8dc0f

Copy Constructor 0x1efdc20

Destructor 0x7fffecb8dc0f

Constructor 0x7fffecb8dc0e

Copy Constructor 0x1efdc41

Copy Constructor 0x1efdc40

Destructor 0x1efdc20

Destructor 0x7fffecb8dc0e

Destructor 0x1efdc40

Destructor 0x1efdc41

which clearly shows the construction and destruction of objects , both on stack  and on heap (0x1efdc20, 0x1efdc40, and 0x1efdc41 are locations of the objects allocated by the vector).